# POI / Tika in Java OSGi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, osgi, apache-tika

This looks like an age old problem.  Wondering if there's an update.

I'm trying to parse Excel in OSGi (Karaf).
Apache POI or TIKA.

I've tried tika-bundle.jar and I've tried a few of the POI uberjars.
Thought tika-bundle.jar would work since it is advertised as for OSGi.  But it can't find "org.apache.tika.config".

I've tried camel-tika.

Anyone had any success with POI/Tika in OSGi, in the last 5 years?

(Note: I'll use anything, if it can read sheets and cells in Excel)

Comment: Googling for `poi karaf` finds https://github.com/BlackBeltTechnology/karaf-features-apache-poi - possibly worth a look. Even if you don't want to use Karaf, you might spot something you can reuse.

Comment: Thanks, in the meantime i've got fastexcel-reader working.  Also a dependency nightmare, but running at least.  Will try that one out next, if this doesn't work.